Google Chrome displays formulas in Latex wrongly on stackexchange, why?
Some formulas in Latex are displayed as boxes like here:

Link to the answer depicted above.
I don't have this problem with Firefox or Safari. I also tried to turn off my extensions. Do you know why Chrome does this?

I guess that's related to how Chrome on (that particular instance of) MacOS renders a calligraphic font, since the issue is with $\mathcal D$ rendering somewhat as $\square$ rather than as $\mathcal D$.
As a fix of the symptom, try right-click on a formula and changing what's used in Math Settings/Math Renderer.
Update: In my browser, this setting is saved for a given site when I close and re-open the browser, perhaps with a cookie. YMMV.

Thanks! Common-HTML and SVG works perfectly. Is it possible to safe this setting permanently for all stackexchange pages?
